# Add a margin to the object

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and I want to prepare a shape like the below image (sum of A and B) for 3D printing. I have designed part A with blender, but I don't know how to design part B and add it to part A. can you help me?
Thanks a lot
[image]

Comment: Do you have a 3D reference?

Answer (score 0):

Create the mesh 1 and the mesh 2:

[image]

Fill the gap between their neck with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*. After that select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to make sure that the faces are correctly flipped:

[image]

Now you have an object that is ready for 3D printing:

[image]